# Parse multiple values from string c#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

Suppose I have written "5 and 6" or "5+6". How can I assign 5 and 6 to two different variables in c# ?

P.S. I also want to do certain work if certain chars are found in string. Suppose I have written 5+5. Will this code do that ?

```
 if(string.Contains("+"))
 {
     sum=x+y;
 }
```

Comment: Regex is the way to go for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Make conditions for this. Like `if (string.Contains("+") || string.Containts("plus") || string.Contains("and") {...}`

Comment: The question is quite vague. What exactly are your requirements? Can there be just about _anything_ between the numbers? Can there be more than 2 numbers? Any targeted solution will need more information than what you have given us so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string input="5+5";

var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Value)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would vote against doing some splitting and regular expression stuff.

Instead I would (and did in the past) use one of the many **Expression Evaluation** libraries, like e.g. [this one over at Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18880/State-of-the-Art-Expression-Evaluation) (and the [updated version over at CodePlex](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/)).

Using the parser/tool above, you could do things like:

[image]

A simple expression evaluation then could look like:

```
Expression e = new Expression("5 + 6");
Debug.Assert(11 == e.Evaluate());
```

To me this is much more error-proof than doing the parsing all by myself, including regular expressions and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another name for your string than `string`

```
var numbers = yourString.Split("+");
var sum = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);
```

Note: Thats an implementation without any error checking or error handling...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "5 and 6";
string[] a = s.Split(new string[] { "and", "+" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(a[0].Trim());
Console.WriteLine(a[1].Trim());
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/JTjbVO).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign numbers from string to variables, you will have to parse string and make conversion.

Simple example, if you have text with only one number

```
string text = "500";
int num = int.Parse(text);
```

Now, if you want to  parse something more complicated, you can use split() and/or regex to get all numbers and operators between them. Than you just iterate array and assign numbers to variables.

```
string text = "500+400";
if (text.Contains("+"))
{
 String[] data = text.Split("+");
 int a = int.Parse(data[0]);
 int b = int.Parse(data[1]);
 int res = a + b;
}
```

Basicly, if you have just 2 numbers and operazor between them, its ok. If you want to make "calculator" you will need something more, like Binary Trees or Stack.

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.Split method. It splits your string rom the given character and returns a string array containing the value that is broken down into multiple pieces depending on the character to break, in this case, its "+".

```
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;

        string value = "5+6";
        if (value.Contains("+"))
        {
            string[] returnedArray = value.Split('+');
            x = Convert.ToInt32(returnedArray[0]);
            y = Convert.ToInt32(returnedArray[1]);
            z = x + y;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may helpful

```
string strMy = "5&6";
char[] arr = strMy.ToCharArray();
List<int> list = new List<int>();
foreach (char item in arr)
{
  int value;
  if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out value))
  {
    list.Add(item);
  }
}
```

list will contains all the integer values

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to get those value and then switch on the operand to do the calculation

```
        string str = "51 + 6";
        str = str.Replace(" ", "");
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<rightHand>\d+)(?<operand>\+|and)(?<leftHand>\d+)");

        var match = regex.Match(str);
        int rightHand = int.Parse(match.Groups["rightHand"].Value);
        int leftHand = int.Parse(match.Groups["leftHand"].Value);
        string op = match.Groups["operand"].Value;

        switch (op)
        {
            case "+":
            .
            .

            .


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split function maybe is comfortable in use but it is space inefficient 
because it needs array of strings 
Maybe Trim(), IndexOf(), Substring() can replace Split() function